# Why did Hermione fall in love with Ron?

Tags: harry-potter

Ron, Harry and Hermione were best friends, as we all know.

However Ron was frequently nasty to Hermione, constantly making jokes about her cleverness and other personality traits. In short, he was very ill-behaved toward Hermione.

That being the case, **can anyone offer specific reasons for why Hermione fell in love with him, either in her own words (or in the words of her creator)?**

Comment: I'm sorry, are you asking for us to logically explain love?  Next I'll mathematically prove a pickle.

Comment: @Alexwlchan : Yes , thanks , you added link :)

Comment: Related, but not dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18501/why-was-ron-so-nasty-to-hermione?rq=1

Comment: @Jeff : No , The point is , despite of Ron was nasty ...

Comment: @Rajan **"The quarrel of lovers is renewal of love."** Old wisdom. But read [this](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2014/2/7/full-wonderland-interview-reveals-ronhermione-shippers-can-relax). I think this one is an acceptable source.

Comment: Why do birds suddenly appear, ev'ry time you are near?

Why do stars fall down from the sky, ev'ry time you walk by?

Just like me, they long to be close to you.

Comment: He might not be doing it intentionally but [some say](http://www.seductionbase.com/seduction/cat/In_the_Middle/cocky/668.html) that being cocky and funny actually works... ;-)

Comment: Opposites attract?

Comment: See also https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/4359/139 "JKR says that Hermione shouldn't have married Ron. Is this correct?" and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133277/4918 "Why didn't Harry Potter marry Hermione?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JKR spoke to this issue in a [recent interview](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/feb/10/jk-rowling-harry-potter-heresy-ron-hermione). Hermione was drawn to Ron because he's funny, the perfect counterpoint to her intensity.

> "Just like her creator, she has a real weakness for a funny man. **These
>   uptight girls, they do like them funny** … It's such a relief from being
>   so intense yourself – you need someone who takes life, or appears to
>   take life, a little more lightheartedly."

---

In the novels, her attraction to him seems to have been fanned by their enforced proximity over the past few weeks, the fact that they're being chased by the Death-Eaters and the fact that Ron actually uses his brain for a change

> ‘But how did you get in there?’ he asked, staring from the fangs to Ron. ‘You need to speak Parseltongue!’
>   ‘He did!’ whispered Hermione. ‘Show him, Ron!’
>   Ron made a horrible, strangled hissing noise.
>   ‘It’s what you did to open the locket,’ he told Harry apologetically. ‘I had to have a few goes to get it right, but,’ he shrugged modestly, ‘we got there in the end.’
>   ‘He was amazing!’ said Hermione. ‘*Amazing*!’

Comment: I hope you didn't edit this answer because you're planning to close my question as a dupe! :-[

Comment: @randal'thor - Tempting, but no. One is asking a general question, the other is asking for a check from the novels themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose if you wanted to be romantic about it, you could say that opposites attract and whatnot.

But actually, JKR has stated in a recent interview that she thinks Ron *isn't* suitable for Hermione, and wishes she had written the epilogue to have Hermione end up with *Harry* instead.

Comment: That's no quite what she said; http://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/feb/02/jk-rowling-hermione-harry-ron-married

Comment: The tldr version: Rowling wanted Hermione and Ron to wind up together, no matter how much the characters had to be stretched to achieve that.  
There's also the fact that Hermione, for all her bossiness, has only two friends in the world*, as far as canon shows.  That's the kind of thing that can leave you with a lot of insecurities, such as the ones she started with, before befriending the boys.
*three if you count Ginny.