# Why was Ron so mean to some people in Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter

In the movie, Ron makes a joke with Harry about how a fat girl from whatever house she was in can't be a swan because she's fat, during a class where McGonagall was teaching and Mr Filch was figuring out how to use a Muggle technology music device.

Then he fights with Harry some way through the movie.

Offends Hermione a couple times.

And pretty much annoys the entirety of Gryffindor sometime before Harry wins the golden egg.

Why was Ron so mean to some people in Goblet of Fire?

Comment: I'll take "*What is Puberty?*" for 500 points, please Alex.

Comment: Add in the fact that he's the youngest (and least note-worthy) of 6 boys, two of whom were Head Boy and two who got a lot of attention as class clowns.

Comment: Don't forget one was also a prefect and captain of the Quidditch team

Comment: Yeah, and his best friend is famous (leaving Ron to always be in the shadow) and his other best friend (Hermione) is super smart leaving Ron to always feel like a dunce.  And puberty.  Yeah, Ron's got reasons to be slightly bent out of shape at times.

Comment: Related but not a dupe https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18501/why-was-ron-so-nasty-to-hermione

Answer (score 16):

- He's 14, poor thing.
- His super famous best friend who's usually so realistic about his life/fame seems to have started seeking attention by putting his name (illegally!) in the Goblet of Fire for a contest which could very well kill him (it has killed people in the past, who were older and more accomplished and grew up in the Wizarding World so they have a better idea of... everything).
- His best friend is competing against one of his idols and one of the more famous Quidditch players, and a beautiful girl. And Cedric. Who is of course perfect. Remnds you that Harry is The Boy Who Lived a bit too strongly.
- The prize for the contest which could kill him? Money. Which Harry already has lots of, like a ridiculous amount of. The Weasleys are... not rich. Ron's got nothing but handmedowns for everything, even his wand.
- His best friend (Only friend? Almost.) is risking his life for something he doesn't even need.
- He's the youngest boy of his family and has yet to distinguish himself by being a dragon tamer, curse breaker, Head Boy/Prefect, The Twins, etc. Except by being Harry Potters Best Friend.
- He's 14 and I know *I* was a moody idiot at 14.

I mean I'd be pissed at the world too.

At a certain point when your life feels like it's falling apart and you might be losing everything you just start lashing out even if you know it's not going to help.

Comment: Also, he allegedly put his name in the Goblet of Fire... without giving Ron the same option, not even an offer.

Comment: Yep that all about sums it up, especially the bit about being 14.  My god, all boys are idiots at 14.  I was, my kids were, my friends were, my grandkids probably will be...  Wizards are certainly not immune to the curse of....HORMONES

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion he was so rude because of how exactly he was put on the back burner throughout the film. Being the youngest and also how he had such feeling about Hermione also because Ron is just a dick. Lets be honest here.

Comment: I’m not sure your last point is really needed here.